# 404 error page not found from server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, yii, http-status-code-404

I have this type of url

```
    http://123.123.123.123/~developers/cakephp/
```

it always give me

```
    404 Not Found

    The server can not find the requested page:

    123.123.123.123/~developers/cakephp/ (port 80)
```

Previously my url is

```
    www.domain_name.com/cakephp
```

and my completes project was run. but now my all cakephp or Yii project displaying 404 page not found. i have print in webroot index.php file, root index.php file but it not displaying my message.

my htaccess file on root

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
     </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to my server settings. I have moved my code on new server then it works perfectly.
So do not change your code check your server htaccess settings.